# Question on Stackoverflow URL format

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, hyperlinks, http

A tradition SO URL use format something like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/foobar
```

My understanding when there is same title, a URL is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234/foobar
```

Why not instead use the following format?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/foobar/123
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/foobar/234
```

Seems it is more natural and more `restful`, right?

**Update: I am not saying only use slug as the only identifier, I just mean the order of the parameter. Since `id` is the unique identifer, it is better to put at the LAST part of the url.**

Comment: Titles can change, question IDs can't. The proposed format would invalidate links if the titles are edited.

Comment: Related: *[Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332237/documentation-for-stack-exchange-engine-urls/332251#332251)*

Answer (score 10):

Not really. The number is the question ID that uniquely identifies the question. The title slug is entirely optional (and often truncated if it's too long, anyway):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/foobar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/
```

both lead to the same page.

Using the title as a primary identifier wouldn't make sense: it's not guaranteed to be unique, and could actually change if the question is edited.

Comment: Or `http://stackoverflowcom/123/not-really-the-title` for that matter.

Comment: @Adam, I am not saying using slug as the  primary identifier, id is still needed, I just mean just swap position!

Comment: @Howard What happens when the title is edited? You'd break every link pointing to the question. My point is that titles could change, which is why they aren't required in the URL and come second.

Comment: @Adam, the system can still look up the new url from the id (which is still a required parameter, but put at the last position)

Comment: @Howard That seems highly unintuitive.